# lxml non-recursive full tag

Tags: python, recursion, lxml

Given the following xml:

```
<node a='1' b='1'>
   <subnode x='25'/>
</node>
```

I would like to extract the tagname and all attributes for the first node, i.e., the verbatim code:

```
<node a='1' b='1'>
```

without the subnode.

For example in Python, `tostring` returns too much:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring("<node a='1' b='1'><subnode x='25'>some text</subnode></node>")
print(etree.tostring(root))
```

returns

```
b'<node a="1" b="1"><subnode x="25">some text</subnode></node>'
```

The following gives the desired result, but is much too verbose:

```
tag = root.tag
for att, val in root.attrib.items():
    tag += ' '+att+'="'+val+'"'
tag = '<'+tag+'>'
print(tag)
```

result:

```
<node a="1" b="1">
```

What is an easier (and guaranteed attribute order preserving) way of doing this?

Comment: *"guaranteed attribute order preserving"* is a huge code smell. What are you trying to do with that `<node a="1" b="1">` string?

Comment: @Tomalak I want to build a new tree out of some higher level and some lower level nodes (skipping the intermediate level nodes), without going through the trouble of actual subtree moving and node removal bookkeeping.

Comment: If tree transformation is your goal, I'd recommend looking at XSLT. It's the most appropriate tool for the task, and XSLT solutions are typically a lot more elegant than the equivalent DOM API code in an imperative language. Post a reasonably complete input document and the desired output for that. That being said, attribute order is insubstantial in XML. Do not create any systems that depend on attribute order in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all of the subnodes.

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring("<node a='1' b='1'><subnode x='25'>some text</subnode></node>")
for subnode in root.xpath("//subnode"):
    subnode.getparent().remove(subnode)

etree.tostring(root)  # '<node a="1" b="1"/>'
```

Alternatively, you can use a simple regex. Order is guaranteed.

```
import re
res = re.search('<(.*?)>', etree.tostring(root))
res.group(1)  # "node a='1' b='1'"
```